# Rails + JQuery + Bootstrap set variable modal class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to setup a button where depending on what item is currently showing in a carousel, it will show the relatively item.  (e.g. Item 1 displayed, press button, details of item 1 are shown; Item 2 displayed, press button, details of item 2 are shown, etc.)

I've tried this code below, which I think I might be getting close but really appreciate any help with this.

See `data-target` below to get an idea of what I've tried along with the `index` I'm trying to use in JQuery to find the current item.

Thanks for any help!  Really appreciate it.

main.html.erb

```
<div id="coverflow">
        <ul class="flip-items">
            <li><%= image_tag "a.png", class: "img-thumbnail creation-thumb" %></li>
            <li><%= image_tag "b.png", class: "img-thumbnail creation-thumb" %></li>                
            <li><%= image_tag "c.png", class: "img-thumbnail creation-thumb" %></li>
            <li><%= image_tag "d.png", class: "img-thumbnail creation-thumb" %></li>            
            <li><%= image_tag "e.png", class: "img-thumbnail creation-thumb" %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <%= link_to "See Details", "", class: "btn btn-primary", "data-toggle"=> "modal", "data-target" => "#portfolio#{}Modal" %>
</div>
```

modal window (Example 1)

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="portfolio1Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal ONE</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

       <p> ONE
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
var flipContainer = $('#coverflow'),
flipItemContainer = flipContainer.find('.flip-items');
var xo = flipItemContainer.children().index
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with rails, but here is the normal way to do it. It should be same concept. Each image has its own button that is hidden when not the active slide. On that button is the associated data you want to display.
Working link is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bpmjmd?editors=1010)

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div id="coverflow">
        <ul class="flip-items">
            <li><img src="a.png" class="img-thumbnail creation-thumb"><a class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-value="first slide" data-target="#myModal">More Details</a></li>
            <li><img src="b.png" class="img-thumbnail creation-thumb" ><a class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-value="second slide" data-target="#myModal">More Details</a></li>
            <li><img src="c.png" class="img-thumbnail creation-thumb" ><a class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-value="third slide" data-target="#myModal">More Details</a></li>
            <li><img src="d.png" class="img-thumbnail creation-thumb"><a class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-value="fourth slide" data-target="#myModal">More Details</a></li>
          <li><img src="d.png" class="img-thumbnail creation-thumb" ><a class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-value="Last slide" data-target="#myModal">
              More Details</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>






<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal ONE</h4>
      </div>
      <div >

       <div class="modal-body2"> This will be changed by data-value from caller
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var content = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-value');
       $("div.modal-body2").text(content)

    });
});
```

Comment: @martin_tuck Thanks for this.  Very helpful.  I'm not positive though how I would hide the button and only show on a specific active slide - could you explain a bit there?